# Authenticate external users in azure AD with GraphApi

Tags: api, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there any way to authenticate an external user with Azure AD through GraphApi?
So far I have been able to authenticate users of the active directory with GraphApi but not the external users. I have been able to identify the invited users but I have not been able to authenticate them.

The authentication of users of the active directory is done in Azure AD. Authentication is not done with the AD on-premisse

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you can use [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) or [OAuth 2.0 resource owner password credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) to get access token.

It works for the users of your tenant and the invited users (work accounts) from external tenants.

**The sample for OAuth 2.0 resource owner password credential**

[image]

**I successful get a token for the invited user (jack@techlearn.top) in my tenant (hanxia.onmicrosoft.com) as following:**
[image]

**And I can use the access token to call the graph api to show all the users in my tenant (hanxia.onmicrosoft.com):**

[image]