# How can I create external users in Azure AD/Enterprise Applications?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, microsoft-graph-api

I have a new .Net Core web application that we are building. We need to use Microsoft Graph in this new application, and it seems that the current way of authenticating and using Microsoft Graph, involves using Azure AD. We used to just add users to a DB and then they would authenticate via OIDC. But now it looks like it's all in the cloud.

So, I created an App Registration and I can find that in my Enterprise Applications list. The part where I'm lost is adding external users. For example, we are creating this app for us and other orgs to use, all of which have their own Azure AD's. I don't want to just allow the entire external org to sign in. So, how can I create external users from the Enterprise Applications page for my app?

There is one SO article, that looks similar, but it's not quite the same: [Authenticate external users in azure AD with GraphApi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56858888/authenticate-external-users-in-azure-ad-with-graphapi)

I've read that I can "send an invitation", but I don't see that option and I really don't want to use that. I want to create external users and assign roles to them, without the whole invite process. So, how do I do this?

UPDATE: Because of my credentials, I know that I can go to the Active Directory and add a user, even an external user. However, this is the AD for the entire company, and I find it hard to believe that this is what I need to do. I know the current way of building apps with security is to use Identity Web, which is essentially Azure AD, but I'm not even sure I'm heading down the correct path here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, it appears the only way to add external users is to add their org to your Azure org, which most companies won't really want to do. Some of that part is beyond my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

> We are creating this app for us and other orgs to use, all of which
> have their own Azure AD's. I don't want to just allow the entire
> external org to sign in. So, how can I create external users from the
> Enterprise Applications page for my app?

Actually, you wouldn't get any straightforward option to include external user directly within your enterprise application which from another app because no such feature available.

Based on your description and scenario what you can do is to create a app within your enterprise app as following:

[image]

Within  your app you need to add user whom do you want to include means the external user in Assign users and groups or directly click on Users and Group option. Finally assign previllage or role to that group. This can be your work around but directly its not allowed at this moment.

[image]

[image]

**Note:** You need higher previllege to accomplish this operation, for instance: [Global Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#global-administrator) or [Application Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#application-administrator).

> I want to create external users and assign roles to them, without the
> whole invite process. So, how do I do this?

I am afraid, you can skip the full invitation process because its by design. Another issue you are not adding external user within the parent app itself here is the main blocking.

However, if you would like to include external user within your app you can invite them using following way:

```cs
        [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateInvitation()
        {
            InvitedUserMessageInfo info = new InvitedUserMessageInfo();
            info.AdditionalData.Add("Data1", "Testing Additional Data");
            info.AdditionalData.Add("Data2", "Testing Another Additional Data");
            var invitation = new Invitation
            {
                InvitedUserEmailAddress = "usreemail@domain.com",
                InviteRedirectUrl = "https://yourapp.domain.com",
                InvitedUserMessageInfo = info
            };

            await _graphServiceClient.Invitations
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(invitation);
            return Ok();
        }
```

**Note:** Please be aware of following permission. You can [get more details here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I can add users at the Active Directory level, but that is the AD for our entire company, which I find it hard to believe that I can only add external users that way. Please see my update above.

Comment: I have seen your update and as you know we cannot directly add external user only. Thus,  the I have explained is the work around. You need to add user either in new app or app userGroup within the app. Its been a quite ages I got a [`similar kind of issue but in different context`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57232810/assigning-licenses-to-a-guest-user/57233189#57233189) which resolved in same way as there were no direct way.

Comment: First, I don't understand why Microsoft would want developers to use this authentication method and then not provide an easy way to add external users. I might as well go back to the DB days. I also don't quite understand your work around. I need to define a new app? If I do that, I can add external users to the new app? If I add a UserGroup within my existing App, I can add external users there?

Comment: As you already observed that we cannot add external users within enterprise app. So, if we create new app within that we can create a group that there we will be adding all required external users . If I add a UserGroup within my existing App, I can add external users there? Yes you can. The point is, you then can assign your role which also were question.

Comment: Okay, so I went to the Enterprise app registration. I did not see an option to add another app withing this one. I also tried to add a new group, but all I could do is select existing groups. I'm guessing this is because of my permissions?

Comment: It might be because of your role, you need higher previllege to accomplish this operation, for instance: Global Administrator or Application Administrator which I have also mensioned on my answer.